# Is Google's Webspeech server request-limiting me, and is there a fix?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, speech-recognition

I've been writing an extension that allows the user to issue voice commands to control their browser, and things were going great until I hit a catastrophic problem. It goes like this:

The speech recognition object is in continuous mode, and whenever the `onerror: 'no-speech'` or `onend` events fire, it restarts. This way, the extension is constantly waiting to accept input and reacts whenever a command is issued, even after 5 minutes of silence.

After a few days of of development, today I reached the point where I was testing it in practical use, and I found that after a little while (and with no change to anything on my part), my `onend` event started firing **constantly**. As in, looking at the console, I would see 18,000 requests being made in the space of three seconds, all being instantly denied, thus triggering `onend` and restarting the request.

I'm aware that it would be optimal to wait for sound before sending a request, or to have local speech recognition capabilities without the need for a remote server, but the present API does not allow that.

Are my suspicions correct? Am I getting request limited?

Comment: https://www.talater.com/annyang/ Seems to be taking continuous speech recognition, judging by the flashing tab, but it also doesn't seem to be working at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are my suspicions correct? Am I getting request limited?

Yes

> I'm aware that it would be optimal to wait for sound before sending a request, or to have local speech recognition capabilities without the need for a remote server, but the present API does not allow that.

To hide the IP source of your request you can use anonymizer networks like Tor, though it will not be fast.

It's naive to assume Google will spend resources to process all audio being recorded on your system. In your application development it is better to rely on API which provides at least some guarantees. It could be either commercial API or open source implementation like CMUSphinx.

With CMUSphinx, you can also properly implement command keyword detection and increase accuracy by specifying the grammar of the commands.

Comment: But if that's true, how has [this site](https://www.talater.com/annyang/) achieved the same functionality I'm seeking to implement, and without request limiting? I studied [the source](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/blob/master/annyang.js) and couldn't figure out the difference.

Comment: I think their demo could be blocked for excessive usage too.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Voice Activity Detection (VAD) algorithm to detect when a user is talking. This can be done by either setting a volume threshold or a frequency threshold (Human speech is usually less than 400hz for example). This way, you won't send useless requests to Google unless those conditions are meant. I would not recommend using Tor as this would significantly increase latency. CMUSphinx is probably the best local system option, but if still want to use a web-based service, I would recommend either using a Voice Activity Detection algorithm or finding a different web-based software.

Comment: Could you give some example/info of how to to do VAD with Javascript? I wasn't sure such a thing was currently possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not fluent in Javascript, but I do have an API library written in Java if you want some example code.